# Confusion with Cancan nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm trying to set up Cancan authorization for a nested resource, and I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

My system is set up as follows

```
    class Listing
      has_many :listing_openings

    class ListingOpening
      belongs_to :listing

    class ListingOpeningsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user! #checks user is logged in
      load_and_authorize_resource :listing
      load_and_authorize_resource :listing_opening, :through => :listing #as per cancan docs for nested resources

    ability.rb
      can [ :index, :create ], ListingOpening, :listing => { :user_id => user.id } #user must own listing
      can [ :update ], ListingOpening, :listing => { :user_id => user.id }

    routes.rb
      resources :listings, :except => [ :destroy ] do
        resources :listing_openings, :except => [ :destroy, :show ]
      end
```

To edit an opening, the path is /listings/800/listing_openings/7/edit. Cancan is correctly checking that listing 800 is owned by the current user and returning it as @listing, and saying 'not authorized' otherwise. However, it is not checking that opening ID 7 belongs to listing 800. Instead of saying 'not authorised', it is raising a 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' error when I try to enter an invalid opening ID. In a way, this works , but surely it should be giving the same error as if I try to edit a listing I don't own. 3 queries appear to be being generated by Cancan, which look like this

```
    Listing Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "800"]]
    ListingOpening Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "listing_openings".* FROM "listing_openings" WHERE "listing_openings"."listing_id" = $1 AND "listing_openings"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["listing_id", 800], ["id", "7"]]
    Listing Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 800]]
```

What is the best way to go about this - it should only need 2 queries. Am I on the right track?